# mat-select-trigger without ellipsis and multiline | mat-select multiple

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to prevent the `mat-select-trigger` from showing ellipses and the content from not being hidden. Currently this is what happens:

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxLayout="row wrap">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple fxLayout="row wrap">
    <mat-select-trigger fxLayout="row wrap">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let dato of toppings.value; let i = index">
        <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary" (click)="eliminar(i)">{{
          dato
        }}</span>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{
      topping
    }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
  toppings = new FormControl('');

  toppingList: string[] = new Array(100).fill(null).map((x, i:number)=> i+' Paso' + Math.random())
```

I tried to remove it with scss but the content is still displayed on a second line.

```scss
mat-select-value {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-overflow: none;
    white-space: normal;
}

.mat-select-value-text {
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: auto;
    text-overflow: none;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What version of Material are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Material v15, you can do it like this:

```css
.mat-select-value {
  text-overflow: clip !important;
}
```

---

If you are using Material v15, you can do it like this:

```css
.mat-mdc-select-value {
  text-overflow: clip !important;
}
```

Comment: I use v13, but still not working.

Comment: Did you add `.` before the class name in your `scss`? Because in your code above you have `mat-select-value` instead of `.mat-select-value`

Comment: Yes. I fix that in my scss. I going to create an example in stackblitz.

Comment: Please include the StackBlitz in the question too.